# PHP - sort associative array by another indexed array

Tags: php

I have the following arrays:

```
$arr = array(
 'keyA' => 'valueA',
 'keyB' => 'valueB',
 'keyC' => 'valueC',
 'keyD' => 'valueD'
);

$order = array('3', '4', '1', '2');
```

I need to sort $arr based on $order so the output be

```
array(
   'keyC' => 'valueC',
   'keyD' => 'valueD', 
   'keyA' => 'valueA',
   'keyB' => 'valueB'
```

);

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: check array_multisort() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @DampeS8N: That works but it will also change the order of the `$order` array. Just mentioning. So you might want to make a copy of `$order` first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array( 'keyA' => 'valueA', 'keyB' => 'valueB', 'keyC' => 'valueC', 'keyD' => 'valueD' );

$order = array('3', '4', '1', '2');

array_multisort($order, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```